# Unexpected behavior with MINUS - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a query like below (Query1)

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 ,COLUMN4
FROM (SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4 
       FROM TABLE1 join TABLE3 ON JOINCONDITION 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON JOINCONDITION2
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT COLUMN5,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN6
       FROM TABLE5 join TABLE3 ON JOINCONDITION 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON JOINCONDITION3
       )
```

I have optimized the above query and derived the following query (Query2)

```
SELECT CASE CONDITION... COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,CASE CONDITION.. AS COLUMN4
FROM (SELECT COLUMN2,COLUMN3
       FROM TABLE1
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT COLUMN2,COLUMN3
       FROM TABLE5 )
 JOIN TABLE3 ON JOINCONDITION
 LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON JOINCONDITION2
 LEFT JOIN TABLE5 ON JOINCONDITION3
```

COLUMN3 - DATE datatype

COLUMN2 - USERIDs

To validate the new query (Query2), I tried to execute both the queries with MINUS operator like below

QUERY3:

```
QUERY1 WHERE COLUMN2 BETWEEN 17150 AND 20000
MINUS
QUERY2 WHERE COLUMN2 BETWEEN 17150 AND 20000
```

This results in 5 rows with COLUMN2=17480. Then I tried

QUERY4:

```
QUERY2 WHERE COLUMN2 BETWEEN 17150 AND 20000
MINUS
QUERY1 WHERE COLUMN2 BETWEEN 17150 AND 20000
```

I get the same 5 rows with same values. All the columns are matching exactly between both QUERY3 and QUERY4. COLUMN3 also having same date & time values (From Year till seconds) between QUERY3 and QUERY4.

Then I tried giving the value directly like below. This query returns nothing

```
QUERY1
WHERE COLUMN2 =17480
MINUS
QUERY2
WHERE COLUMN2 =17480
```

Even if I interchange the position of QUERY1 and QUERY2 in between the MINUS operator, no results. 
One more thing to note is, there is no results even if I reduce the range in the BETWEEN clause in QUERY3 and QUERY4.

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Do you get at least those 5 rows if you just do the first part of your query, i.e. `SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 
FROM TABLE join TABLE3 ON JOINCONDITION
WHERE COLUMN2 =17480` ?

Comment: I am getting more than 5 rows from each query separately.

Comment: If the _5 rows_ are having same data in both queries, `MINUS` will be giving *0 rows* . Can you add the output of the first query in your question? The one with `between`.

Comment: Are the number of rows returned same for both of the queries?

Comment: What do the execution plans show for both queries? The optimiser may be doing something different as it knows the second query is more selective. Are they all actually tables, or are any views? The predicate may be pushed differently if there are views involved. But even so, that sounds like it might be a bug, possibly. Or a corrupt index. It's hard to tell without the data and plans, and with the query obfuscated so much.

Comment: Can you please post the results of the 2 subqueries separately and for both cases ?

Comment: 2nd query is optimized version of first query. So execution plan changes but both the queries are supposed to bring same result set. 
The queries return same number of records. When I compare the results manually, they match with each other without any differences. 
COLUMN3 is a DATE column and there is no difference in the values between first and second query even in seconds. 
If I remove this date column(COLUMN3) in the query with between condition, no records are returned. If I keep this DATE column when run with single COLUMN2 value condition, no records are returned

Comment: You should probably add most of that to the question. By "2nd query is optimized version of first query" do you mean the second branch of your first query, with `between`? I was referring to comparing the overall plan for the entire first query (`between`) with the second (`=`). Or, possibly, the comparing the first branch of each, and the second branch of each. It might help to indicate which table each column comes from, but probably not. Without [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) the description sounds like a bug... What happens if you reverse the two branches in the `between`?

Comment: Can you provide execution plans of the two queries, as follows: select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ADVANCED' ) )